# Property SubItems is ReadOnly and more

Tags: vb.net

Tried to convert C# to VB, but I keep getting the following errors:

Property subitems is ReadOnly

and

Value of type String() cannot be converted to ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection

My code is as follows:

```
ListView1.Items.Clear()
        For int_0 As Integer = 0 To 17
            Dim tuple As Tuple(Of String, String, String) = pullMem(int_0)
            If tuple.Item3.Contains("09") Then
                Me.ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(tuple.Item1) With {
                            .SubItems = {tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3}
                        })
            End If
        Next int_0
    Catch e1 As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("You must connect first!", "Error")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can't instantiate the subitems like that in VB.Net.  Try just creating the ListView item and then add the subitems to it:

```
Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(tuple.Item1)
lvi.SubItems.AddRange({tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3}.ToArray())
ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
```